# What happened to Diane in "Shaft"?

Tags: plot-explanation, shaft

In the 2000 movie *Shaft*, the final judgment never takes place, since the charged person (Walter Wade, Jr.) is murdered before he enters the court.

Diane had confessed to Shaft, in a private conversation, that she got bribed to hide the truth (she was a witness in the murder of Trey by Walter). Do *we know* if she got away with that?

The movie doesn't mention that, I think. She's not a protagonist, so maybe we don't really know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John Shaft II (Samuel L Jackson) has no reason to bring Diane to the authorities for accepting a bribe for hiding the truth.  No District Attorney has any reason to suspect her so they wouldn't press charges either.

Remember, Shaft quits the police force to become a private detective.  His interactions with her are confidential and it's at his discretion to bring this information to the police or district attorney.

Comment: He even says to her "the last two years must have been hell for you" or something similar, so it's pretty clear he understands her conflict (and deems it enough of a punishment).